# Segmentation fault in solving dynamic problem

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, overflow, dynamic-programming

Is there any difference in these type of calculating ans in dynamic problems ? Because in case of Code 3 I am getting segmentation fault while Code 1 and Code 2 are passing

```
int dp[8005][2];//dp is initialized as -1 in main
int a=4;
int b=6;
int tar=90;


int solve(int pos,int ba)
{
    
    if(pos<0||pos>8000||ba>=2)
        return 1e6+1;
    
    if(pos==tar)
        return 0;

    //Code 1
    int &ans=dp[pos][ba];
    if(ans!=-1)
       return dp[pos][ba];
    ans=1+solve(pos+a,0);
    ans=min(ans,1+solve(pos-b,ba+1));
    return ans;

    //Code 2
    if(dp[pos][ba]!=-1)
       return dp[pos][ba];
      dp[pos][ba]=1+solve(pos+a,0);
        dp[pos][ba]=min(dp[pos][ba],1+solve(pos-b,ba+1));
        return dp[pos][ba]; 
    
    //Code 3
  if(dp[pos][ba]!=-1)
       return dp[pos][ba];
   int ans=1+solve(pos+a,0);
    ans=min(ans,1+solve(pos-b,ba+1));
    return dp[pos][ba]=ans;
}
```

Comment: I have added the base cases actually. How its an endless recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code 3 doesn't update `dp` until *after* all the calculations are done.

The first two go

- Recurse
- Update `dp`
- Recurse
- Update `dp`
- Return new value

Note that 1 and 2 are equivalent, since `ans` is the same as `dp[pos][ba]`.

The third is

- Recurse
- Recurse
- Update `dp` and return the new value